# android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException . Need to use async task to solve this issue?

Tags: java, android-listview, android-asynctask, networkonmainthread

I got this error when i'am trying to get some date for a listview, when I searched about it I found that its solution is to use async task, but don't know how to use it, so how I can use it in my code?

here is the code:

```
package com.example.ms;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import com.example.ms.XMLParser;
import com.example.ms.LazyAdapter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class PhotosActivity extends Activity {

    ListView list;
    LazyAdapter adapter;
    static final String KEY_SONG = "song"; // parent node
    static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    static final String KEY_ARTIST = "artist";
    static final String KEY_DURATION = "duration";
    static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumb_url";
    static final String URL = "http://api.androidhive.info/music/music.xml";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_photos);

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_SONG);

        // looping through all song nodes <song>
                for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
                    map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
                    map.put(KEY_ARTIST, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ARTIST));
                    map.put(KEY_DURATION, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DURATION));
                    map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, parser.getValue(e, KEY_THUMB_URL));

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    songsList.add(map);
                }

        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.photoslist);

        // Getting adapter by passing xml data ArrayList
        adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, songsList);        
        list.setAdapter(adapter);


        // Click event for single list row
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {


            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.photos, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: where is your asynctask code?. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: I don't know how to do it exactly, this is my first android app.

Comment: check the docs and learn how to code asynctask then if you run into problems come back and ask the same here. there is an example in the link posted i my previous comment

Answer (score 1):

Yes you must run the Parsing code , especially the call where you do a http call parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); in a separated thread. i.e. in AsyncTask. So copy your code onto AsyncTask.doInBackground() and return from doInbackground() the parsed List. In AsyncTask.onPostExecution(List) you will receive your parsed list and thats the right point to set the ListView adapter, simce this method will be executrd on the main UI thread.

public class PhotosActivity extends Activity {

```
private XmlParserTask task;

public void onCreate(Bundle saved){
     super.onCreate(Bundle saved);
    // Do your UI setup
    task = new XmlParserTask();
    task.execute(URL);
 }


public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    // Avoid Memory leaks and android view not attached to window manager Exceptions
    if (task != null)
        task.cancel(true);
 }


private class XmlParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<YouSongType>> {

     public List<YourSongType> doInBackground(String ... params){

         String url = params[0];

         List<YourSongType> resultList = new ArrayList<YourSongType>();

        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_SONG);

       // Add your xml parsed data in the list
       resultList.add();

       return resultList;
    }


   public void onPostExecution(List<YourSongType> songsList){
      adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, songsList);        
      list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


}
```

Comment: I have added a little code snippet. Just to give you a idea. Important is, that you have to cancel the AsyncTask, if the Activity gets destroyed (i.e. the user clicks the back button), because the AsyncTask will run even after the Activity has been destroyed and than will try to post back the result to an Activity that does not is active anymore.
One more thing you may dont know is starting from Android 3.0 AsyncTask execute one after each other (and waits until the one is finished, before starting the next). If you want to run AsyncTask parallel use executeOnExecutor() instead of execute()

Comment: Btw. don't forget to mark the correct solution to your question :D

Comment: their is a problem in adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, songsList);, what should be replaced with "this" ?

Comment: PhotosActivity.this
But you could also instantiate the adapter in the onCreate() of the activity and add a method to set the list to the adapter. Something like `adapter.setSongs(songsList)` and then do `adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()`

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because you are trying to grab data from network and you do that on main thread!

```
`String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL);`
```

As you have said you need to fire any kind of thread to avoid long process on mainthread, one of the options is AsyncTask, using AsyncTask is straight forward basically you have three methods `onPreExecute() doInBackground()` and  `onPostExecute()`

`onPreExecute()` and `onPostExecute()` run on UI thread you can use them to display dialog, result, or feed your list from your xml data

`doInBackground()` run on netowrk thread so you implement that to grab the xml from server, you can the in `onPostExcute()` make use of delegation to update you list from result of `doInBackground()`